# Add a title to pop up window w/ this code---

Tags: javascript, popup, soundcloud

Where in the code can I add a name for the pop up window??

```
code: (embedded in wix flash site)
<script language="javascript"><!--

function PopUp() {

    var PopWidth = "400";
    var PopHeight = "220";
    var PosTop = "200";
    var PosLeft = "200";

var SettingS = "toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=" + PopWidth + ",height=" + PopHeight + ",top=" + PosTop + ",left=" + PosLeft;
var PopUp = open("","box",SettingS);
PopUp.document.clear();
PopUp.document.write('<object height="200" width="100%"> <param name="movie" value="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fplaylists%2F434705&amp;show_comments=true&amp;auto_play=true&amp;show_playcount=true&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;color=3f1081"></param> <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param> <embed allowscriptaccess="always" height="360" src="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fplaylists%2F434705&amp;show_comments=true&amp;auto_play=true&amp;show_playcount=true&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;color=3f1081" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%"></embed> </object>   <span><a href="http://soundcloud.com/patrickharlin/sets/apps-set">Music by Patrick Harlin</a> by <a href="http://soundcloud.com/patrickharlin">Patrick Harlin</a></span>');
}

window.onload=PopUp;

// -->
</script>
```

I am using a popup in wix via embeddable html, as a music player hosting internal content. I am trying to troubleshoot why my popup works in most browsers but not IE9.  The best I can tell is that I need to name my popup window, and I'd like to name it either way...

Thanks

The site in ? can be found here: www.patrickharlin.com

Answer (score 0):

You add the title in the `head` element of the HTML page you are opening.

This would be the standard [`title` HTML element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/struct/global.html#h-7.4.2).